# JQuery remove images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm curious if anyone knows why this piece of jQuery code doesn't remove the images?

```
var a = $('#tblMain').clone().remove('img');
```

The table is being selected.  This is trying to take the table on the webpage and export to excel but I do not want the images to export.

Thank you,

Comment: `(img)` refers to a variable name, don't you perhaps want `('img')` as a selector?

Comment: Put your comment in as the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$("#tblMain").clone().find("img").remove();
```

EDIT: Okay, here's the problem:

> selector: A selector expression that
>   filters the set of matched elements to
>   be removed.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

The `img` in `.remove('img')` is to filter the set of items in the jquery object, NOT to find elements within the items themselves.  In this case, the jquery object contains only one item, the cloned table.  Therefore, `.remove('img')` removes nothing, since the jquery object does not contain any images (only images within items it contains).

Comment: This isn't keeping the rest of the table.   Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not keeping the rest of the table.  I believe this is the best way to do it.  If you mean for chaining purposes, you can use `.end` to go back to the table itself.  Something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/rFVVv/  or alternatively assign the table to a variable before using find.

Comment: Thank you, the solution ended up being `$("#tblMain").clone().find("img").remove().end();`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what's happening behind the scenes, but you're referring to some variable called `img` whilst you most probably just want to *select* all `img` elements. In that case, you ought to use a selector as a **string**:

```
var a = $('#tblMain').clone().remove('img');
```

---

**EDIT:** `.clone.remove` does not seem to work indeed. I used this workaround which actually works:

```
.find('img').each(function() {$(this).remove()});
```

Comment: I apologize, I have fixed the code stated above.  I do have have 'img' in the code.

Comment: Something is your edit isn't clicking with me. `$(#tblMain').clone().find('img')` will just return the imagines. if you remove it, then a would be blank.

Comment: Thank you pimvdb see below for the solution.